# What does it mean for all norms are elementwise over matrix entries

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I am reading this [paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~dlsun/papers/universal_speech_models.pdf) where they introduce 4 types of norm penalties which induce sparsity in the matrix block $H_g$ in table 1. For example, $\log/ l_1$ is $\sum_{g} log(\epsilon +  \lVert H_{g} \rVert_1)$.

As the definition of  $\lVert H_{g} \rVert_1$, it is the maximum absolute column sum of the matrix ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)). But in the paper, they give a description under the table "all norms are elementwise over matrix entries". How can norm are elementwise? I think from the definition, it seems to be columnwise.

Comment: it just means that you consider the $\ell_1$ norm of the "vectorized" form of matrix, i.e., in this case, $\|H_g\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |(H_g)_{i,j}|$.

Comment: @Onetimething So it is "Entrywise matrix norms" [wiki1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms) Not "Matrix norms induced by vector norms" [wiki2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The maximum column sum is the induced vector norm.

Comment: @Onetimething May you explain a bit while it is that type of norm?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, but here are some ideas. (a) in general elementwise $1$-norm is used to promote sparsity (if suppose, you minimize this quantity) in matrices just as is done for vectors. (b) using the definition of induced vector norms, the wiki page you linked to has the derivation to show that the induced $1$-norm is indeed the absolute maximum column sum. Hope this helps.